# How to solve $a^{b^2} = b^a$ in positive integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have this exercise:

$a,b$ are positive integers. Get all $a,b$ numbers that satisfies $a^{b^2} = b^a$

Is hard to me, but I have these advances:

$a,b$ must be both even or both odd, since $a, b$ are the base.

Besides, if $a > b$, the exponent and the exponent of $a$ is $b^2$ and the exponent of $b$ is $a$, therefore $a > b^2$

So far I have managed to develop the exercise, what can I do? How do you work with these types of mathematical problems? Thanks in advance

Comment: Notes:  $a=b=1$ works.  Your observation regarding $2$ works for every prime.  That is, a prime $p$ divides $a$ iff it divides $b$.

Comment: This is the [problem 5 from IMO 1997](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwRtse3UEt8). You can find plenty of solutions if you just google it.

Comment: As @dezdichado mentioned, the solution can be found on various websites ([AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1238p3845), for instance). Usually, when we deal with equations like $x^{y}=z^{t}$ in number theory, writing $x$ and $y$ as the product of their prime factors (for example, $x=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\times \ldots p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}$is useful idea.